# Determine the previous commit during a VSTS release

Tags: azure-devops

When performing a deployment, I'm looking to perform some optimisations depending on whether certain file paths have been changed since the previous release.

Is there a way to find out what the previous commit hash on the target environment was? I'm guessing it would need to go "Previous Release" -> "Build Artifact" -> "Commit", but I'm stuck on the first step.

To clarify, I want to be able to list the commits displayed in the "Deploy" modal:

[image]

Comment: Does your release definition treat build artifacts for release? And for the build definition which generate the build artifacts for release, does it always build for the same git repo?

Comment: Yes, the build artifact is an artifact dependency for the release. And yes, the build always uses the same repo source

Comment: @RichardSzalay I believe there's a REST method you can call. Look at the HTTP requests that are made when you pull that modal up (F12 developer tools, Fiddler, whatever). I can't check right now but I'm pretty sure I've done this in the past.

Answer (score 1):

### If the build definition builds for multiple branches

Then you need to get the last commit sha-1 value by the previous release/build and then get the last commit.
The steps to achieve as below:

1. Get last release

   use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1):

   ```
   GET https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/releases?$top=2&definitionId={id}api-version=4.1-preview.6
   ```

   And you will get last two releases for a certain release definition. And for the two releases, one is the current release you are deploying, the other is last release.
2. Get last buildId from last release

   In the first step, you can get the last release logs from the parameter `logsContainerUrl`. And you can download the last release log to zip and unzip the logs. Then you can get the `buildId` from Download artifact step log.
3. Get last commit sha-1 from buildId

   Use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the last build, and you can get the source version (last commit) from response.

### If the build definition builds for a certain branch

Then the last commit sha-1 value can be got easier by git commands.

You can use a PowerShell task with below script:

```
git clone <URL for git repo> repofolder
cd repofolder
git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
$lastcommit=$(git rev-parse HEAD~)
echo "last commit sha-1 value is $lastcommit"
```

**Note:**

- For the git repo URL, you need to procider credential (such as PAT) inside the URL like:

  `https://Personal%20Access%20Token:PAT@account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo`
- If the build artifacts is not the Primary artifact for release, you should use the variable `$(Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceBranchName)` instead of `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` in powershell script.
- The **Fail on Standard Error** option in PowerShell task should be deselected.

  [image]

Comment: Won't this be the SHA for the build _being_ released? I'm after the SHA for the build that is already on the environment (and about to be replaced). It's recorded somewhere as there's UI for showing the difference between the two.

Comment: Assume commit `A` is for last build and release, commit `B` is for current build. The script will get the commit `A` for last time's build/release during current release

Comment: And isn't that script just a round about way of calculating `$(Release.Artifacts.SourceVersion)`?

Comment: Interesting. Will give it a go and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not. The script is calculate the commit before `$(Release.Artifacts.SourceVersion)`.

Comment: `Build.SourceBranchName` is the branch name, which is always the same. So using `HEAD~` assumes that the commit previous deployed to the environment is the commit immediately before `HEAD`, but there's no guarantee that the previous _release_ is on this environment let alone the previous commit.

Comment: @RichardSzalay Yeah. I realized. It can only meet the situation that the build definition always build same branch. If there are multiple branches trigger builds, you do need to get the last commit by the last release/build. And I updated my answer for this situation.